# Race condition when updating redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, race-condition

I'm using `redux-saga` with `takeEvery` which allows multiple actions to execute simultaneously:

```js
export function* watchSaga() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery(actionTypes.FETCH_DATA, fetchDataSaga)
    ])
}
```

and the `fetchDataSaga` looks like:

```js
export function* fetchDataSaga(action) {
    yield put(actions.fetchDataStart())
    try {
        const response = yield axios.post(url, body)
        yield put(actions.fetchDataSuccess(response.data))
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(actions.fetchDataFail(error.response.data.error))
    }
}
```

in `fetchDataSuccess`, I'm adding a new field (or updating if exist) into my redux state object:

```js
const initialState = {
    myObj: {}
}
...
const fetchDataSuccess = (state, action) => {
    const newKey = action.newKey
    return {
        ...state,
        myObj: {
            ...myObj,
            [newKey]: {
                ...myObj[newKey],
                timestamp: new Date().getTime()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I make concurrent calls to the saga ,let's say 100 times:

```js
yield all([
    call(fetchDataSaga, action[0])
    call(fetchDataSaga, action[1])
    call(fetchDataSaga, action[2])
    ...
    call(fetchDataSaga, action[99])
])
```

There should be 100 fields in `myObj` afterward.

**My question is**, am I going to get the latest state every time in the `fetchDataSuccess` reducer? Or will there be a race condition that one of the reducers read the old previous state, and if so, how can I prevent it?

Comment: What is the actual scenario? What exactly are you trying to achieve? You are going to have races, because as soon as a fetch finishes it updates the state. Any task that finishes late or early would be out of order.

Comment: I want to make sure that there are exactly 100 fields in `myobj`, and the order doesn't matter. My concern is that, if call#99 update the state, `myobj` should then have 99 fields, what if call#100 finish at the same time and when updating te state it read the old `myobj` which hasn't been updated by call#99, so it ends up in only 99 fields in`myobj`.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, you'll be fine. JS has a single thread, so although the fetch calls will be happen parallelly, the actual handling of the responses would happen serially. The only problem is the ugliness of the code (you should use some kind of loop), and the fact that 100 calls at the same time seem like a bad API. The BE should have a single API that returns 100 items.

Comment: Good question.  My instinct is that it's fine but I'm not confident on that.  You should see if you can find anything in the Saga Docs.  https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga.html Have you tried playing with it to see what happens?

Comment: ＠LindaPaiste yeah I know that the callback functions will execute serially, but when I play around it sometimes breaks. In `fetchDataStart` I update `myobj`  with the key. In another saga (other than `fetchDataSuccess`) which I'm sure is called LATER than `fetchDataStart`, it doesn't contain that field. The only possible condition I could come up with is that some of the `fetchDataSuccess` reducers had read the old state while updating it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you @OriDrori .